# how can I use Future/Async function in a loop? (dart/flutter)

Tags: firebase, flutter, asynchronous, dart, async-await

```
        String random_username ;
        bool available = false;
        int n = 0;
        do{
          random_username = SuperHero.random()+(n.toString());
          n = n+1;
          print(random_username);
          checkUsernameAvailable(random_username).then((value){
            available = value;
          });
        }while(!available);
```

What I am trying to do is when a new user is registered in Firebase Auth, I want to create a random username for the user, which can be changed later.
this code should generate a username, check if it is already in firebase database. If no, then leave the loop, else add a suffix number and retry.
(By mistake I've put the name generator in the loop, so every time it will get a new name, and that's okay for now).
The function **checkUsernameAvailable** return "true" if there's no match, i.e available. and vice versa.

The problem is that the loop continues forever. maybe this is due to the async method ,i.e, **checkUsernameAvailable**.
Please help.

Comment: check `Future.doWhile`

Answer (score 12):

You can use [`Future.doWhile()`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.8.4/dart-async/Future/doWhile.html) method, which performs an operation repeatedly until it returns `false` :

```dart
Future.doWhile(() async {
  final random_username = SuperHero.random() + (n.toString());
  n = n + 1;
  print(random_username);
  return !(await checkUsernameAvailable(random_username));
});
```

Comment: Error: A negation operand must have a static type of 'bool'.
Try changing the operand to the '!' operator.dart(non_bool_negation_expression). Actually checkUsernameAvailable returns a Future<bool>. is that the problem?

Comment: Answer updated, you need to await for the result as we return its negation.