# Flutter async/await function

Tags: flutter, async-await

I am new to flutter/dart programming. I am trying BLE connection in flutter using flutter reactive BLE. I want to retry BLE connection if it fails for the first time.

I tried following code, but the while loop here is not waiting for the connection function result (connectToDevice). while loop is executing 3 times without waiting for **connectionStatus**. I want to exit loop once connection happens and when it returns true. Please help me with how to wait till connection function returns a value and based on returned value execute the loop.

```
 Future<bool> connect(DiscoveredDevice foundDevice) async
  {
     count=0;
     bool connectionStatus=false;
     while(!connectionStatus && count<3)
       {
         connectionStatus =   await (connectToDevice(foundDevice));
         count++;
         
       }
         
     return connectionStatus;
  }
static Future<bool> connectToDevice(DiscoveredDevice foundDevice) async {
  // Once scanning done, cancel the scanning
    _scanStream.cancel();
  
  
     await (flutterReactiveBle.connectToAdvertisingDevice(
    id: foundDevice.id,
    withServices: [serviceUuid],
    prescanDuration: const Duration(seconds: 5),
    servicesWithCharacteristicsToDiscover: {serviceUuid: [readCharacteristicUuid]},
    connectionTimeout: const Duration(seconds:  2), //
  ).listen((connectionState) {
  // Handle connection state updates
      print("Connection Status");
      print(connectionState);
    switch (connectionState.connectionState) {
  // Connected.
    case DeviceConnectionState.connected:{
      _rxCharacteristic = QualifiedCharacteristic(
      serviceId: serviceUuid,
      characteristicId: readCharacteristicUuid,
      deviceId: connectionState.deviceId);
      print(_rxCharacteristic);
      _connected=true;
      found_BLE_device=foundDevice;
      break;
  }
 
    case DeviceConnectionState.disconnected:
    {
      print("Disconnected BLE");
     _connected=false;
     break;
    }
    default:
      _connected=false;
      break;
  }
  }, onError: (dynamic error) {
     print("ERROR");
    

  }));
   return _connected;

  }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how can I use Future/Async function in a loop? (dart/flutter)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62693486/how-can-i-use-future-async-function-in-a-loop-dart-flutter)

Comment: Thank you, I tried Future.doWhile, It's calling the function continuously without waiting for  the result.

Comment: Use the debug, place break points in places where you believe the method does not wait.